# jQuery Flotcharts.js - zoom error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I have this error with my plot when i add zoom in options:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined | jquery.flot.navigate.js:105
```

My code:

```
function plotSetUp(XTYPE_) {
    console.log('plotSetup')
    XTYPE = XTYPE_;
    var V = [];
    var PRK = [];
    var r = 0;
    if (!MONIT[CAR.id].route || MONIT[CAR.id].route.err) {
        V.push([0, 0]);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < PTS.length; i++) {
            if (XTYPE == 'points') {
                V.push([i, PTS[i].v]);
                (PTS[i].key) ? PRK.push([i, null]): PRK.push([i, 100]);
            } else if (XTYPE == 'time') {
                V.push([getMsFromDate(PTS[i].dt), PTS[i].v]);
                (PTS[i].key) ? PRK.push([getMsFromDate(PTS[i].dt), -20]): PRK.push([getMsFromDate(PTS[i].dt), 255]);
            } else if (XTYPE == 'road') {
                log(PTS[i].rgps);
                V.push([PTS[i].rtah, PTS[i].v]);
            }
        }
    }
    var mode = null;
    if (XTYPE == 'time') mode = 'time';
    var options = {
        grid: {
            clickable: true,
            hoverable: true
        },
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 0,
                fillColor: {
                    colors: [{
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        opacity: 1
                    }]
                },
            },
        },
        colors: ["rgba(41, 150, 206, 0.9)", "rgba(67, 90, 110, 0.4)", ],
        crosshair: {
            mode: "x",
            color: "#323232",
            lineWidth: 1,
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: mode,
            show: true,
            position: "bottom",
            color: "#323232",
            font: {
                size: 10,
                lineHeight: 15,
            },
            labelHeight: 15,
        },
        yaxis: {
            show: true,
            position: "left",
            color: "#323232",
            labelWidth: 20,
            font: {
                size: 10,
            },
            max: 150,
            min: 0,
        },
        pan: {
             interactive: true,
             cursor: "move",
             frameRate: 60,
         },
        zoom: {
            interactive: true
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            id: 'flotTip',
            content: '%x : %y km/h',
            shifts: {
                x: 10,
                y: 20,
            },
            defaultTheme: true,
            lines: {
                track: false,
                threshold: 0.05,
            },
        }
    };
```

This is happen when i scroll over flot. How to fix it?

PS: Need to add more text, cos its mostly code but explained well :o
and more and more

Comment: I build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gttn305a/) based on your code and it works fine. Make sure you load jquery before flot and flot before the navigate plugin. If that is not the cause, create a fiddle which reproduces your error.

Comment: Hmm, i also have same error when i scroll over jquery.knob   ( http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ ) but why its give me error to jquery.flot.navigate.js:105 ?

Comment: In line 105 the complete `jquery.mousewheel.min.js` plugin is included. The error appears to be in there, but I don't know why you get an error. For me it is working fine.

Comment: What browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: It happens on all browsers.